# Matrix with rank more than $1$

Tags: notation, convention

Is there a shorter way of saying that a matrix $A$ has rank more than $1$? I am looking for something like "full-rank", or "rank-deficient."

Comment: If you don't like those terms, which are very well known, you could also think about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Kernel.2C_image_and_the_rank.E2.80.93nullity_theorem